# The OSX firewall prompts to "accept incoming network connections" when creating a ServerSocket

Tags: java, macos, sockets, firewall, serversocket

I'm using sockets to communicate between local processes. This causes the OSX firewall to prompt:

```
Do you want the application "Foo.app" to accept incoming network connections?
```

I have two problems:

- Ideally the prompt should not appear, since the socket is only for local use
- The dialog appears then immediately disappears, so the user doesn't have time to click "Allow" or "Deny".

The code:

```
new ServerSocket();
```

Note that specifying localhost or 127.0.0.1 does not prevent the prompt either:

```
new ServerSocket(0, 0, InetAddress.getByName(null));
```

Comment: Have you tried 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: @Thilo: 0.0.0.0 is the default, so that's not going to help. Also, if 127.0.0.1 doesn't help, 0.0.0.0 isn't going to either.

Comment: Have you tried signing your app? I believe that with default settings, 10.5 allows anyone to listen to 127.0.0.1, while 10.6+ only allows signed apps to listen to 127.0.0.1 (possibly requiring Gatekeeper-compatible signing in 10.8, but I don't think so). But I haven't really tested.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. If the user checked "Automatically allow signed software to receive incoming connections", then OSX adds the app to the allowed list.

Comment: I think code signing needs to satisfy OSX, but I'm not sure what the exact requirements are (I've seen codesign -vvv report valid/satisfies but the firewall still prompts).